# how to create dynamic folders based on dates in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I want to create a folder dynamically for keep my logs on daily basis. For example
in 'D:/AppLog/' folder there will be folder called '21-07-2016' which contains logs of particular date only. in the same folder there will be folder called '22-07-2016' which contains logs of particular date only

```html
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=D:/AppLog/one.log

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, should not overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

# Set the maximum file size before rollover
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=100KB

# Set the the backup index
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=1000

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}  %m%n
```

That was my log4j.properties file. Please help me for this. Thank you

Comment: Untested, but have you tried what is described in the FAQ: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#separate_log_files

There, the `filePattern` contains variables for the folder names as well. So maybe just using such patterns for the filename will be enough.

Comment: no i havn't tried that can you help me how to add that in .properties file. I am new to log4j.

Answer (score 1):

you can do as following ,

Set the name of the file

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L] %m%n
log4j.appender.fileappender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the instructions found here https://programmersought.com/article/26231133742/

Put this on your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.logErrFile.File=D:/AppLog/${log4j_file_path}/error_logs.log
```

Then in your Java code put something like this:

```
String dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
System.setProperty("log4j_file_path", dateFormat); 

PropertyConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.properties"));
```